# Assign integer value to heap

Tags: c++

```
  #include<iostream>
  using namespace std;
  int main() 
  { 
    int i= new int;
    cout<<i;
    return 0;
  }
```

when i tried to assign int i value to heap it shows 
**error: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int'**

when i assign value to int pointer then it assign to it.why we cannot assign value to int to heap.Yes i know as much as possible avoid assigning value to heap.
I looked many stackoverflow post everyone explained about int *p=new int[10];
Please someone explain this to me.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have wrong declaration. declare it as int *arr = new int[100];

Comment: @RaviHirani: No!!!!!!!!!

Comment: My mistake,  int i = new int(); Is equal to 

int i = 0;

Comment: @Ravi ::  thats I want to ask..it is stil possible to write int i = new int(); instead of int i = 0;

Comment: Yes it is possible. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @Ravi getting this : error: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int'                   [-fpermissive]    int i = new int();

Comment: Let me look into it.

Comment: @Ravi as per my understanding after reading books and over internet. new return pointer to memory block from heap.so it should be assigned to pointer that is on stack. So we cannot do such kind of operation.

Comment: @InvI: Yes. I am agree with you. int * pointer = new int; reserves one ticket. Let take some experts comments on this.

Comment: @Ravi: whom u r calling for comment on this.

Answer (score 10):

`new int` returns a pointer to `int`, that is, `int*`. Assigning it to an `int` is an obvious type mismatch.

The pointer returned by `new T` points to a memory location on the heap a.k.a. free store, which provides enough space to store one object of type `T`. `T` is an arbitrary type here.

Your code could be altered to this:

```
int* ptr = new int;
*ptr = 1;
cout << *ptr;    // prints 1
```

**Don't forget to** `delete` **afterwards!**

---

Note that the heap should only be used for dynamic data used beyond scope boundaries. In your case, it's way too heavyweight. Just use a good old automatic variable:

```
int i = 1;
```

Comment: don't `free` memory gotten via `new`; use C++'s `delete` instead.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Oh holy crap, sorry, confused both. Updated.

Comment: Don't worry, not that catastrophical :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Well, yes, it is.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit if you do that in code, yes. If you do it here and correct it in seconds, then not.

Answer (score 1):

```
new int;
```

**allocates** memory for a single int, initializes one int in there, and gives you a pointer to that. It doesn't give you an `int` but a pointer to `int`, hence `int*`.

You probably just want to do

```
int i = 42;
```

or so.

**EDIT**:

You can of course also do

```
int* i = new int;
```

but the way you use it, you shouldn't do that. Memory gotten via `new` stays allocated until you `delete` it; that means that you'd code a memory leak if you used `new` without `delete`.

Comment: No i just want to clear my concept that is there any way i can do such thing,

Comment: you can also do `int* i = new int;` of course, but only if you really want a freshly allocated variable. You should really read up on the differences between pointers and variables, and what `new` does.